# selenium webdriver run firefox on the VMware

Tags: firefox, selenium, nunit, webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I set a virtual machine and I want to use it to run my daily test.

But it cannot start FirefoxDriver.

In the beginning, I thought it's my code problem.

But it can run test with Firefox on my physical machine.
And if I change it to IE Driver, the program can be run in the virtual machine.

Firefox version is 10.

I thought it's not a version problem because I can use the same version to run the test on the physical machine.

Comment: What error message do you get when FirefoxDriver is unable to be started?

Comment: SetUp :system argumentnullexception :value cannot be null

Comment: Unfortunately his exception is not very informative. Is the whole stacktrace accessible?

Comment: Sorry, that's all ....I,ve met this before,maybe it mean I didn't start the webdriver up to let it test.  so sad.

Comment: Is your local machine x64 bit and the virtual machine x32? Your code may not find the firefox binary.

Comment: @_@ machine is x64 bit and where can I know is the program find firefox binary

Comment: Strange indeed. Can you run the test in debug mode (via Visual Studio) and see the line in the code where it throws the exception? You may get more info with it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that:

1. Your test has access to Firefox binary
2. Your geckodriver.exe is available in the PATH system environment variable (you might also want to test by adding the driver just in the same directory where you have your script)
3. Compatibility between Firefox version and Geckodriver [compatbility matrix](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/Support.html)
4. Since you didn't mention what OS does the VM have; if it is linux then you should verify that firefox binary does have the required permissions
   (u+x permissions)
5. Another recommendation is also to update your setup to latest versions so that you can benefit from available bugfixes and also improvements.